# Good ways to measure screen for use with Orthographic clipping planes

Tags: android, opengl-es, parameters, screen, orthographic

Hey I'm converting my project so that it uses orthographic projection because I've been told its simpler and ideal for 2D games.  I don't know really know how I'm meant to measure the screen parameters for the clipping planes.  I could hard code numbers but that would cause stretching when the screen is put into landscape.  I don't even really know if the clipping planes are meant to be fixed to the edge of the screen but that appears to be the case because I've been trying different numbers and the larger the numbers the smaller the drawn shape gets.  That leads me to assume that the numbers I'm putting in are just the extreme ends of the axis.

Are my assumptions correct?

What is the best way to avoid the stretching?

What commands are best for finding the size of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah Ha Just got it =)

Just realised that my onSurfaceChanged Method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, -width, width , -height, height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

gl.glViewPort finds the screen size and after a bit of playing I finally got a centre aligned image with no stretching when orientation is changed using the line

```
GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, -width, width , -height, height);
```

Someone correct me if there is a better way to implement this =)